# Filtering data using checkbox

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

For default must show items that have prop "state: 'notarchived'" and "state: 'archived'" must be hided
When I have a Check I need hide elemets with "state: 'notarchived'" and show elements with  "state: 'archived'"

There my HTML

```
<th><input ng-model="archived.state"  type="checkbox"
      ng-true-value="'archived'" ng-false-value="undefined">Show archived</th>


<tr  ng-repeat="paymentinfo in paymentList | filter:keyword | filter:money | filter:getdate | filter:{state: 'notarchived'}: archived.state ? true : true">
          <td>{{paymentinfo.date}}</td>
          <td ng-click="singlepage(paymentinfo.id)" ><a>{{paymentinfo.name}}</a> </td></tr>
```

JS

```
 $scope.datas = [
            {date:'06-12-2016', name : 'Pinao Class', state: 'archived', remark : 'remarled', amount : 101, id : 21},
            {date:'15-04-2016', name : 'drivers Class', state: 'notarchived', remark : 'remarled', amount : 102, id : 22},
            {date:'24-03-2016', name : 'Airplane Class', state: 'archived', remark : 'remarled', amount : 103, id : 23}

    ];

$scope.paymentList = $scope.datas;
```

Now displayes all elements
How to change filter that it work right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

Set the initial value for the checkbox:

```
<input ng-model="archived.state"  type="checkbox"
      ng-true-value="'archived'" ng-false-value="'notarchived'" 
      ng-init="archived.state='notarchived'">Show archived</th>
```

and change the filter:

```
<tr ng-repeat="paymentinfo in paymentList | filter:keyword | filter:money | filter:getdate | filter:{state: archived.state}:true">
```

I tried and it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested for I don't have a proper environment setup

`<th><input ng-model="archived.state"  type="checkbox" ng-true-value="'archived'" ng-false-value="'notarchived'">Show archived</th>`

`filter:{state: archived.state ? 'archived' : 'notarchived'}`

Please test and let me know.
Thanks!

Comment: For default. show notarchived, after pressing check all items displaying, after uncheck. nothing happens